# Retrieve unique values from a column with lists of values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that has one column in which the values are lists of values.

My intent is to split this column using some technique from here:
[Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

However, for the column names I want to use each unique value from those lists of values.

To retrieve the unique values I have tried three different methods.  Each one has failed with a different reason.

Is there a way to get Series.unique() when the values are a list of values?

My three attempts, with associated tracebacks:

```
1)
unique_vals = splitted_interests.unique()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    unique_vals = splitted_interests.unique()
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1991, in unique
    result = super().unique()
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1405, in unique
    result = unique1d(values)
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py", line 405, in unique
    uniques = table.unique(values)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1767, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.unique
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1718, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable._unique
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'


2)
unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: x.unique())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 68, in <module>
    unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: x.unique())
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4045, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 68, in <lambda>
    unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: x.unique())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'unique'

3)
unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: [y.unique() for y in x])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4045, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 68, in <lambda>
    unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: [y.unique() for y in x])
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 68, in <listcomp>
    unique_vals = splitted_interests.apply(lambda x: [y.unique() for y in x])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

At run time, the column with lists looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For same ordering create dictionaries and extract `keys`, solution working in [python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39537308):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'JobRoleInterest':['aa,ss,ss','dd,ff','k,dd,dd,dd', 'j,gg']})
splitted_interests = df['JobRoleInterest'].str.split(',')

unique_vals = list(dict.fromkeys([y for x in splitted_interests for y in x]).keys())
print (unique_vals)
['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'k', 'j', 'gg']
```

Comment: ```@jezrael```,  close, but not really what I was after.  In your answers above I still see items duplicated.  dd appears in 1 and 2.  It also appears twice in 2, which for a set I thought was impossible.  All I am after is a list of the unique values so I can create column names from it.

Comment: No.  Just a list of every unique value from all of the lists in the column.  I will use that list to create column names.  Then I plan to split the one column with list of values into multiple columns (one per unique value) with a single value per one of the techniques in the link I mentioned in my post.

Comment: ```@jezrael```  [aa, ss, dd, ff, k, j, gg]  Single list (or set).  One of each value.

Comment: ```@jezrael``` If other rows had matching values, I don't want\need them.  Just a single entry per value anywhere in the entire column.

Comment: @MarkS - I am confused, why is solution now not what need?

Comment: ```@jezrael```  I was at a location where my browser had not refreshed.  I had not seen your updated answer.  I just ran it and I got what I was after.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

"To retrieve the unique values I have tried three different methods. Each one has failed with a different reason."

you may wanna try astype('str') to retrieve unique values in a column:

```
df.<column>.astype('str').unique()
```

Comment: This answer should get more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

I think you need, `pd.Series.unique`

Using @jezrael data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'JobRoleInterest':['aa,ss,ss','dd,ff','k,dd,dd,dd', 'j,gg']})

df['JobRoleInterest'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack().unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'k', 'j', 'gg']
```

## Update using list data per @MarkS comments below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'JobRoleInterest':[['aa','ss','ss'],['dd','ff'],['k','dd','dd','dd'],['j','gg']]})
df['JobRoleInterest'].explode().unique().tolist()
```

Output:

```
['aa', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'k', 'j', 'gg']
```

Comment: ```@ScottBoston``` I tried yours as well but I am getting back an empty list.  Note the data in my lists in the column are not structured the way @jezrael structured his.  Look above at the screen shot.  Using @jezrael's data, it would be:  ['aa', 'ss', 'ss', 'dd', 'ff', 'k', 'dd', 'dd', 'dd', 'j', 'gg']

Comment: ```@ScottBoston```  That worked as well, and it's easier (for me, at least) to understand. Much obliged.